# How can I stop sourcing a (t)csh script on a certain condition without exiting the shell?

Tags: syntax-error, exit, csh, tcsh

I have to source a tcsh script to modify environment variables.

Some tests are to be done and if any fails the sourcing shall stop *without* exiting the shell. I do not want to run the script as a subprocess because I would need to modify env variables in the parent process which a subprocess cannot do. This is similar but different to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041576/how-to-run-a-tcsh-shell-command-and-selectively-ignore-the-status) where the author actually can run the script as a subprocess.

The usual workaround is to create an alias which runs a script (csh/bash/perl/python/...) which writes a tempfile with all the env var settings and at the end sources & deletes that tempfile. [Here's more info for those interested (demoing a solution for bash)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/496776/923794). For my very simple and short stuff I'm doing that additional alias is not wanted.

So my workaround is to provoke a syntax error which stops any `source` execution. Here's an example:

```
test $ADMIN_USER = `filetest -U: $SOME_FILE` || "Error: Admin user must own admin file"
```

The shortcircuit `||` causes the error text to be ignored in case of goodness. On a test failure the error text is interpreted as a command, not found, the source stops and produces a reasonable error message:

```
Error: Admin user must own admin file: Command not found.
```

Is there any nicer way in doing this? Some csh/tcsh built-in that I've overlooked?

Comment: why not just a conditional block around the conditional variables, i.e. `if ( \`filetest -U: $SOMEFILE\` ) ; then set vars ; else set ohter vars endif`. Sorry my (t)csh syntax is rather rusty, so I'm not certain about the need for `( parens )`. Good luck.

Comment: The problem is not with the control flow inside the `source`. The problem is with stopping sourc'ing the script without exiting the shell it was sourced from. If I would create an `if` conditional for a test, the `else` would span to the end of the file. That's unwieldy for ten or so tests (nesting!). - Unless I can combine all tests to one (or few) locations, which I am not sure that I want to do.

Comment: Come to think about it, this problem exist in the same way in a bash script, doesn't it?

Comment: yes, would be same problem in most shells. I'm surprised that your `...|| "Error: Admin..."` thingy stops the sourcing of a file while letting the surrounding script continue. I would have expected it to report the error and continue with the next line of the sourced file. This may be one in the feature column for (t)csh! Good luck.

Comment: "the surrounding script" is just the interactive shell. That is why I cannot use a simple `exit` command. If a sourc'ed script does an `exit` that would exit the interactive shell

Comment: Oh. Wait. That was my assumption. Just tested and it does not exit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to a discussion with the [user shellter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter) I just verified my assumption that

```
test $ADMIN_USER = `filetest -U: $SOME_FILE` || \
  echo "Error: Admin user must own admin file" && \
    exit
```

would actually quit the enclosing interactive shell. But it does not.

So the answer to my above question actually is:

Just use a normal `exit` and the `source` will stop sourcing the script while keeping the calling interactive shell running.

Comment: So (t)csh is different? My experience (in ksh and bash) is that any `exit` that is not in a sub-process will close the current interactive shell. (I don't have any access to a (t)csh environment). Good luck.